# How do I make a sentence with "Was + past participle" that is not passive?

Tags: passive-voice

Is it possible to make a sentence with "Was + past participle" that is not passive?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I couldn't come up with one. Did you find one?

Comment: Hi. I am not sure.  please check this: "Did you buy that? No, it was sold". Is "it was sold" passive?

Comment: "sold" is both the past tense and past participle of "sell". "It was sold" is in passive voice. In present tense: I sell a ring to you. -> The ring is sold to you. In past tense: I sold a ring to you. -> The ring was sold to you.

Comment: @Damkerng Thank you. Would you please suggest a good source to learn more about this?

Comment: You can find many of them in http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english. I personally like *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan. It's written in clear and easy to understand style. The book also discusses English grammar and usage *alphabetically*, so you can jump right into any issues you are in doubt at any time.

Comment: You can have a past participle after "be" in a sentence that is not passive, the past participle is then used as an adjective. For example: He is/was gone.

Comment: I would like to add examples where the adjectives look like the past participles. I am worried that you haven't called me. I am pleased to meet you. I am surprised to find that you have been married.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct such sentences in the active voice if you use the past participle as an adjective.

For example, "I had a hideous truck. It was burnt orange." In this sentence, *burnt* is a past participle of *burn* but acting as an adjective modifying the color orange.

But!  You say, "*burnt orange* is a compound noun that describes a specific color, and is more like a name than a verb." So . . . Another example:

"Q: What did you order on your pizza yesterday? A: It was smoked sausage." Here, *smoked* is the past participle of *smoke*, acting as an adjective, that fits your formula.

Answer (score 2):

While she **was gone**, the children wrecked havoc.

He **[was done in](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/done+in)** for the day.